# Notification (not method) when Auto layout Trait Collection changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

Is there some kind of system wide notification when the Auto Layout Trait Collection changes in iOS 9+?

I know the `UIViewController` method `traitCollectionDidChange` but I would like to handle the trait change in the App Delegate which does not have this method.

The goal is to inform all (relevant) ViewControllers immediately when the change happens. `traitCollectionDidChange` is only called for the top most VC and when a VC becomes visible/active again.

Comment: - (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator. Try this method.

Comment: This method is part of the `UIContentContainer` protocol, which is not implemented by the App Delegate, is it? So how to make use of this method in the delegate (or in other parts outside the a ViewController)?

Comment: You could use the key window's trait collection `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.traitCollection`. Or the other option is for  ask your first view controller for the trait collection.

Comment: keyWindow? was depreciated in iOS13 sadly

Comment: But there is still a `keyWindow` in `UIWindowScene`. If you App is scene based.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the traitCollection from the screen object `UIScreen.main.traitCollection` and attach an observer to it.

On iOS 13+ you can also read the `UITraitCollection.current` property.

Answer (score 0):

If your App is scene based, you could implement `windowScene(_:didUpdate:interfaceOrientation:traitCollection:)` in your Apps scene `UIWindowSceneDelegate`. You could send a custom `NSNotification` from that method to notify the view controller and other interested objects in your App about the change.